# Swing: how to intercept when Component isDisplayable() become false

Tags: java, swing

My scenario:
I have some `JEditorPane` registered to a `ObjectManager` to do things such like:

```
public MyPane extends JEditorPane{

public MyPane(Parent parent)
  {
   super();
  parent.getObjectManger().registerManagedPanes(this);
   }
}
```

Anytime the code creates it register itself to the Manager.

I have the needs to unregister `MyPane` when it become unavailable, that means when

```
MyPane.isDisplayable() == false
```

I need something like that

```
//MyPane
parent.getObjectManger().unregisterFromManagedPane(this);
```

By looking at `Component` implementation I was basically that `isDisplayable()` returns false when `peer` is `null`. I'd like to not go so deep, there's any `JComponent` (or any other super or extended object)'s method I can override to obtain a behaviour like

```
//MyPane
@Override
public FooOrVoid lookingForThisMethod()
{
  if (!isDisplayable())
{
    parent.getObjectManger().unregisterFromManagedPane(this);
}
return super();
}
```

If this approach is wrong, there's any other approach to archive this behaviour?

Thanx in advice

Comment: You might try [`AncestorListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html).

Comment: I'd like to not use Listeners if possible, however I'm checking AncestorListener thanx @trashgod